# Filling selects with js/jQuery based on first select

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I use [this](http://pastebin.com/fqALF26W) code to fill select options based on the first select. That works just fine. But when I submit the form (still using ajax), and then try to pick a different select option, the last select turns blank.

You can see it in action [here](http://trofast.lakaweb.com/mpwars/), so you know what I mean. I'm not that comfortable with jQuery, perhaps that's the problem here. =)

Any ideas? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using named indexes and an implied global, so your `game` should be defined differently, this:

```
game = [];
```

should be:

```
var game = {};
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Can you please explain the difference and why the first causes it to fail.

Comment: @Lasse - The first is an array that's no longer defined when it comes back, so it's trying to access the game name on an undefined variable.  The reason you want an object is you're using it as object, an array has integer keys, not named ones...that's precisely what an object is for.

Comment: I knew it wasn't defined no more when the form was submitted, but didn't think that I could use objects instead. How does the object "keep" the values?

Comment: @Lasse - it doesn't, a valid reference is the same reference there from when you started, it's just created once on `document.ready`...it's just that the other invalid array method had...side-effects, some of which will be unpredictable cross-browser.

Comment: Hehe, okay, I'm a little confused. =) Don't see the difference between accessing the array with numbered indexes or named ones. What side effect?

Comment: @Lasse - they don't store that way basically, it's just not how an *array* should be used - because you're accessing by index which is different on an array vs an object, it overloads the indexer access when it inherits from object.